# Calculating Fourier transform with residue, last step

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, residue-calculus

I got a rather specific question for when calculating Fourier transform with residue, hoping someone understand what I'm looking for and can help me!

My solution is rather long, but it's only the last step I'm not getting correct. Therefore I will not show my whole solution.

So I want to compute Fourier transform of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^4+4x^2+4}$$

using Residue Theorem.

So first we assume we have negative $t$ in our transform so nothing explodes.

This is done correctly I get my answer to $$\widehat{f(x)}(t) = \frac{-\pi e^{t \sqrt{2}}}{8}(2t-\sqrt{2}), t \leq 0$$

Since function is real we know that $$\widehat{f(x)}(t) = \overline{\widehat{f(x)}(-t)}$$

So now we want to expand is for the function to be valid with $t \in \mathbb R$.

My answer to this is $$\widehat{f(x)}(t) = \frac{-\pi e^{-t \sqrt{2}}}{8}(-2t-\sqrt{2}), t > 0$$

while the correct answer according to the course literature is $$\widehat{f(x)}(t) = \frac{-\pi e^{t \sqrt{2}}}{8}(-2t-\sqrt{2}), t > 0.$$

I would like to argue that this is wrong, since it would explode as $t \to -\infty$, or am I wrong?

Comment: It's a nice and smooth function, so yeah you are right, it does not make sense that the high frequencies should dominate the frequency spectrum. Likely just a small typo in the provided answer.

Comment: btw it is possible to check the answer using WA ( https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=fourier+transform+1%2F%28x%5E4+%2B+4x%5E2%2B4%29 ). Just note that they probably use a different convention (the symmetrical one) so it might different from yours by a factor of $\sqrt{2\pi}$ or similar.

Comment: why should "negative t"  be needed? The exponential is complex and the range is $(-\infty,\infty)$

Comment: Indeed, the range is $(-\infty,\infty)$. However, when computing the integral I need to take into account for which t the function is valid for, so that it does not explode for some t. After that is done I expand the function so it is valid for whole range.

Comment: The Fourier transform of a radial function should indeed be radial. So indeed when you get the value for $t<0$, you get the general formula with $t$ replaced by $-|t|$.

Comment: I still don't understand how the FT $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx e^{ixt} {1\over x^4+x^2 +4} $ is sensitive to the sight of $t$